# why we are using range(len(A) +1) instead of (len(A)) in python

Tags: python

Please help to understand the use of (len(A)+1) in below Python Code Sample

```
def printsublist(A): 
   result = [[ ]]  
   for i in range(len(A) + 1):   
      for j in range(i + 1, len(A) + 1):         
         sub = A[i:j] 
         result.append(sub) 
   return result

# Driver Code
list = [4,5,6]
print(printsublist(list))
```

output : [[], [4], [4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5], [5, 6], [6]]

Comment: Because the ```range```'s last number is always ```stop-1```. So to take all the elements, ```+1``` is added.

Comment: `i` loop has values 0-3. At `i=3`, `i+1=4` and `len(A)+1=4`, so `j` loop fails to run (last iteration of `i` only). This avoids placing the index out of range.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason for the + 1 is to account for the last element.
As mention in a another comment, given a number n, range will go from 0 to n-1(unless given start and step parameters).
Next, when slice a list to include elements from position x to y (included) you must write it like this: list[startIndex:endIndex+1], that is because slicing doesn’t include the end index so if you want to include the element in the end index you must add a plus 1.

Comment: getting confused instead of using range(len(A)) which will go start from 0 to 2(if we have 3 elements in the list). but range(len(A) +1) start from 0 to 3 if we have 3 element in list. It should give out of index error?

Comment: Edited my comment to a correct one now. My apologies for the confusion, but also remember that indexing starts from zero, so if you have 3 elements in a list, trying to reach index no.3 would give an index error because the largest index would be two.

Answer (score 0):

`range()` takes 3 parameters:

- `start` - Starting number
- `stop` - Ending number
- `step` - Skip by how much

However, the last number generated by `range` is always `stop-1`. So if the list is `[1,2,3,4]`, the length is `4`. But if you do `range(len(A))`, it will generate: `0,1,2,3` because the last number is always `stop-1` where `stop` here is `len(A)` which is 4. So when you do `len(A)+1`, 1 is added to `len(A)` which is 4 + 1 = 5. So the last number of `range()` is `stop - 1` which is 4. Hence, all the elements of the list are accessed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification appreciate it.

Comment: @DiyaVinee consider accepting and upvoting the answer